# How to grouby one column and do nothing to other columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
  a  b  c  d 
0 1  1  1  1
1 1  2  2  2
2 1  3  3  3
3 1  4  4  4
4 2  1  1  1
5 2  2  2  2
6 2  3  3  3
```

How to groupby 'a', and do nothing to column b c d, and split into several dataframes? Like this:
First groupby column 'a':

```
  a  b  c  d 
0 1  1  1  1
1    2  2  2
2    3  3  3
3    4  4  4
4 2  1  1  1
5    2  2  2
6    3  3  3
```

And then split into different dataframes based on numbers in 'a':

```
dataframe 1:

      a  b  c  d 
    0 1  1  1  1
    1    2  2  2
    2    3  3  3
    3    4  4  4
dataframe 2:
      a  b  c  d 
    0 2  1  1  1
    1    2  2  2
    2    3  3  3
:
:
:
dataframe n:
      a  b  c  d 
    0 n  1  1  1
    1    2  2  2
    2    3  3  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over each group that `df.groupby` returns.

```
for _, g in df.groupby('a'):
     print(g, '\n')

   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  2  2  2
2  1  3  3  3
3  1  4  4  4 

   a  b  c  d
4  2  1  1  1
5  2  2  2  2
6  2  3  3  3
```

If you want a dict of dataframes, I'd recommend:

```
df_dict = {idx : g for idx, g in df.groupby('a')}
```

Here, `idx` is the unique `a` value.

---

A couple of nifty techniques courtesy [Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869521/how-to-grouby-one-column-and-do-nothing-to-other-columns-in-pandas/46869591?noredirect=1#comment80686432_46869591):

```
df_dict = dict(list(df.groupby('a')))  # for a dictionary
```

And,

```
idxs, dfs = zip(*df.groupby('a'))       # separate lists
idxs
(1, 2)

dfs
(   a  b  c  d
 0  1  1  1  1
 1  1  2  2  2
 2  1  3  3  3
 3  1  4  4  4,    a  b  c  d
 4  2  1  1  1
 5  2  2  2  2
 6  2  3  3  3)
```

Comment: `dict(list(df.groupby('a')))` also works for a dictionary.  And `zip(*df.groupby(a))` for separate lists.

Comment: @root Wow! That's so piR-esque. Thanks.

Comment: Nice one ~ :- )

Answer (score 1):

This is the way by using `np.split`

```
idx=df.a.diff().fillna(0).nonzero()[0]
dfs = np.split(df, idx, axis=0)

dfs
Out[210]: 
[   a  b  c  d
 0  1  1  1  1
 1  1  2  2  2
 2  1  3  3  3
 3  1  4  4  4,    a  b  c  d
 4  2  1  1  1
 5  2  2  2  2
 6  2  3  3  3]
dfs[0]
Out[211]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  2  2  2
2  1  3  3  3
3  1  4  4  4
```